# Concurent (multi-user) processes for flask background tasks?

Tags: python, flask, concurrency, multiprocessing, wsgi

I have a simple python tool hosted on an ubuntu Linux server (HTML Form + Flask + Python code);

**Phases:** Data taken from HTML Form into the backend and processed by a python code and then return a result.

User interface (HTML form) ->> Flask ->> Python script processing ->> return result.

the problem is that processing is taking some time, and if two users open the tool page and trying to submit data simultaneously or before the first user finishes, the tool fails and raise error 500. I figured that all users share the same python script process. and if they're using tool together, the script got interrupted by the last submit.

**How can I make the tool to start different process per user submit?**

*This is just for simple clarification:*

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" name="basic_form">
<input type="text" name="some_data" required>
</form>
```

**Python:**

```
@app.route('/tool', methods=['GET','POST'])
def processing ():
    required_input = request.form['some_data']
    result = *some processing functions*
    return render_template('result.html',result=result)
```